# Aligning in linearlayout

Tags: android

I am using linear layout.I have to achive this :

[image]

I tried something like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="0.25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="login to app"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
<View
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="0.25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

But result is:

[image]

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `center_vertical` to all your `android:layout_gravity`. For example:

```
android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

**UPDATE #1**

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        layout_width="match_parent"
        layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="0.25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:text="login to app"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       <View
           android:layout_width="88dp"
           android:layout_height="0.25dp"
           android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
           android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
           android:background="#ffffff" />        

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Other stuff -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did like this: http://pastebin.com/57Et3mV7 It doesn't work.Can you  give me edited code ?

Comment: @Okan Did it change the appearance of these views at all?

Comment: Yes I changed but still same result.

Comment: Can you give me edited code ? I think I don't understand exactly

Comment: As far as I know it should work. Can you remove `center_horizontal` from the `TextView` and let me know the result

Comment: @Okan `center_horizontal` inside a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout` is meaningless!

Comment: I think we need one more linearlayout(horizontal)

Comment: @Okan No one LinearLayout for this purpose I think is adequate. Is your current LinearLayout horizontally oriented?

Comment: Okay, now you would need another LinearLayout!

Comment: How can I do can you give me an example ?

Comment: @Okan I've changed it with another way, test it!